# PIL Image temporarily displaying before disappearing

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

What's Happening:

When I open my newly saved file from either my GUI directory or directly through the show() method, the file opens and displays the 50% transparent image for probably about a tenth of a second - then stops displaying it completely. The file remains open, but only shows white.

My Problem:

I want the image displayed to stay there, I don't want it to immediately disappear - and I can't figure out why it's disappearing.

My Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL

my_image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\capga\Documents\Art\KT_art.png')
my_image.format
#returns 'PNG'
my_image.mode
#returns 'RGBA'

image_rgba = my_image.copy()
image_rgba.putalpha(128)
image_rgba.save(r'C:\Users\capga\Documents\Art\KT__rgba.png')
image_rgba.show()
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this.In my computer,it won't disappear immediately.Is this all of your code?Maybe you can change another software to see the picture.

Comment: Yea - this is literally all my code, exactly as it is. Dang. Any idea on what software I should use? It's a PNG file. Note - when I "open" with the standard Windows photos app it disappears. But when I 'edit" with Photos it sticks there. I don't know why there would be such a discrepancy.